# How to use grep result with sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have two .dat files. In first is text ID:name and in second ID:size. I have to create third file which would be ID:name:size.
I am pretty much new in terminal and i did something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
egrep '[[:alnum:]]+:' file2.dat | sort > new.dat
cat new.dat > file2.dat
egrep '[[:alnum:]]+:' file1.dat | sort > new.dat
cat new.dat > file1.dat

while read -r line
do
    echo "$line" > temp
    egrep -o ':[[:alnum:]]+' temp
done < file2.dat
```

Next idea is to use sed 's/$//' new.dat combined with egrep written up in text, but i just can't get that.

My question is if it is possible how can I do it in some other way or how can I combine this commands.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: input format is described in text (ID:name, ID:size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look into `man join`, instead using a loop in bash and grep.

e.g.

file1.dat:

```
a:foo
b:bar
c:baz
```

file2.dat:

```
a:1
b:2
```

run:

`join -t : file1.dat file2.dat`

or as James Brown suggests (for unsorted files):

`join -t : <(sort file1.dat) <(sort file2.dat)`

to get:

```
a:foo:1
b:bar:2
```

Comment: Great and welcome! Look into the argument `-a` in case you need to add non-matching lines...

Comment: Remember, that the files need to be sorted when using `join`. If not, you could `join -t : <(sort file1.dat) <(sort file2.dat)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one in awk:

```
$ awk -F':' '$1 in a{print a[$1] FS $2;next}{a[$1]=$0}' f1 f2
a:foo:1
b:bar:2
```

Explained:

```
awk -F':' '             # use : as field separator
$1 in a {               # if key in the first field has already been seen
    print a[$1] FS $2;  # output corresponding array (=record from f1) and $2 of f2
    next }              # no need to process this record further, skip to next
{
    a[$1]=$0            # store record from f1 to hash a using first field as a key
}' f1 f2
```